# H2 SQL Query column not found in scope

Tags: sql, h2

In relation with : [SQL: Find unavailability per minute of a ressource in an appointment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67640181/sql-find-unavailability-per-minute-of-a-ressource-in-an-appointment)

((click above link for schema + info))

I'm trying to run this query in an H2 SQL database. I'm a little unfamiliar with H2 syntax. I noted the column **num** in the WHERE clause that causes the issue.

Error:

> Column "NUM" not found; SQL statement:
> CREATE FORCE VIEW (
> SELECT
> "A"."APPOINTMENT_ID",
> "A"."APPOINTMENT_START_TIME",
> "A"."APPOINTMENT_END_TIME",
> "C"."COMPONENT_HOST_NAME",
> 'unavailable' AS "STATE"
> FROM "PUBLIC"."APPOINTMENT" "A"
> LEFT OUTER JOIN "PUBLIC"."APPOINTMENT_COMPONENT" "AC"
> ON "A"."APPOINTMENT_ID" = "AC"."APPOINTMENT_ID"
> INNER JOIN "PUBLIC"."COMPONENT" "C"
> ON "C"."COMPONENT_ID" = "AC"."COMPONENT_ID"
> WHERE ((CONVERT("A"."APPOINTMENT_START_TIME", TIME) <= DATEADD('minute', "NUM", CAST('00:00:00' AS TIME)))
> AND (CONVERT("A"."APPOINTMENT_END_TIME", TIME) >= DATEADD('minute', "NUM", CAST('00:00:00' AS TIME))))
> AND ("C"."COMPONENT_ID" IN(1))
> FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
> ) AS
> SELECT
> "A"."APPOINTMENT_ID",
> "A"."APPOINTMENT_START_TIME",
> "A"."APPOINTMENT_END_TIME",
> "C"."COMPONENT_HOST_NAME",
> 'unavailable' AS "STATE"
> FROM "PUBLIC"."APPOINTMENT" "A"
> LEFT OUTER JOIN "PUBLIC"."APPOINTMENT_COMPONENT" "AC"
> ON "A"."APPOINTMENT_ID" = "AC"."APPOINTMENT_ID"
> INNER JOIN "PUBLIC"."COMPONENT" "C"
> ON "C"."COMPONENT_ID" = "AC"."COMPONENT_ID"
> WHERE ((CONVERT("A"."APPOINTMENT_START_TIME", TIME) <= DATEADD('minute', "NUM", CAST('00:00:00' AS TIME)))
> AND (CONVERT("A"."APPOINTMENT_END_TIME", TIME) >= DATEADD('minute', "NUM", CAST('00:00:00' AS TIME))))
> AND ("C"."COMPONENT_ID" IN(1))
> FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY [42122-200] 42S22/42122 (Help)

---

My code:

```
with times(num) as 
(
  select 30 as num
  union all select (num + 30)
  from times where num < (24*60)
)
select dateadd('minute', num, cast('00:00:00' as time)) as datetimeinterval, unavailabilities.state from times
outer join(
select top 1 a.appointment_id, a.appointment_start_time, a.appointment_end_time, c.component_host_name, 'unavailable' as state
    from  appointment a 
    left join appointment_component ac on a.appointment_id = ac.appointment_id
    inner join component c on c.component_id = ac.component_id
    where
            dateadd('minute', -->num<--, cast('00:00:00' as time)) between convert(a.appointment_start_time, time) and convert(a.appointment_end_time, time)
    and 
        c.component_id in (1)
) unavailabilities
```

TLDR: Trying to get unavailabilities of a list of components by the minute or by a range of minutes (30 minutes here). Num should return a multiple of 30 in this case, depending on the time frame selected for which it will check if the components are taken or not.

N.B. I changed machine=component and appmach=appointment_component (cross table) from the link above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about the syntax. I am not very much familiar with H2. But isn't `num` should be used in on clause instead of subquery ? Please check:

```
with recursive times(num) as 
(
  select 30 as num
  union all select (num + 30)
  from times where num < (24*60)
)
select dateadd('minute', num, cast('00:00:00' as time)) as datetimeinterval, unavailabilities.state from times
outer join(
select top 1 a.appointment_id, a.appointment_start_time, a.appointment_end_time, c.component_host_name, 'unavailable' as state
    from  appointment a 
    left join appointment_component ac on a.appointment_id = ac.appointment_id
    inner join component c on c.component_id = ac.component_id
    where
            dateadd('minute', -->num<--, cast('00:00:00' as time)) between convert(a.appointment_start_time, time) and convert(a.appointment_end_time, time)
    and 
        c.component_id in (1)


   ) unavailabilities 
on dateadd('minute', num, cast('00:00:00' as time)) between convert(appointment_start_time, time) and convert(appointment_end_time, time)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Still getting the same error.

I will update the full error in post

Comment: I don't have H2 db. Please let me know if you know any online compiler for H2?

Comment: Closest thing I found is this : https://www.jooq.org/translate/ need to select H2 but it's not working as a compiler. I'm using the installed online interface, couldn't find any online ones

Comment: Good read:  http://www.h2database.com/html/advanced.html#recursive_queries

Comment: I think you solved my issue!!!! Thank you! I just changed the outer join to left outer join and deleted my where clause.

Comment: That's great. You are most welcome. Best wishes.